# Google Sheet cross sheet data

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(L:L,MATCH(R3,N:N,0),1),"no match")
```

So this formula is working, I just need it pull data from a different spreadsheet.  Specifically the "L:L" and "N:N" part.

I tried using IMPORTRANGE but I am not having any luck.

Comment: Add the name of the sheet: instead of L:L something like sheet4!L:L, even selecting the other sheet when building the function can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried IMPORTRANGE and not working cause you missed in some of parameter of that.

I'm using IMPORTRANGE before few months and it's working fine.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_D4s78gEyWSDB0CWKnw","XXXX XXXX!D2")
```

- first parameter is sheet url
- in second parameter have sheet name and cell id.
  ex:, 'XXXX XXXX!D2' in this 'XXXX XXXX' is sheet name and 'D2' is cell id

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just figured it out. I was just putting the IMPORTRANGE in the wrong place. Thanks for the response.